# How to install X11 Xevie extension to compile Xevie-based programs

Tags: xorg, software-installation

Is there a command to install [Xevie](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/XEvIE/) (for X11 programming) from repository?

(so that `Xevie.h` will be available for programming)

I need it to compile this sample in Qt Creator:

```
/* xeviedemo.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xproto.h>
#include <X11/X.h>
#include <X11/extensions/Xevie.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>


static void
print_key_event (XEvent *ev)
{
    XKeyEvent *key_ev;
    char buffer[20];
    int bufsize = 19;
    KeySym key;
    XComposeStatus compose;
    int char_count;

    key_ev = (XKeyEvent *)ev;

    printf ("        State: %x KeyCode: %x\n", key_ev->state & ShiftMask, key_ev->keycode);
    char_count = XLookupString(key_ev, buffer, bufsize, &key, &compose);
    buffer[char_count] = '\0';
    printf ("        Char Count: %d KeySym: %x char: |%c|\n", char_count, key, buffer[0]);
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Display *dpy;
    int major, minor;
    XEvent  event;
    XClientMessageEvent *xcme;
    int count = 0;
    long delay = 0;
    int ret;

    if (argc > 2)
    {
        printf ("Usage: xeviedemo delay (in milliseconds)\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (argc == 2)
    {
        delay = strtol(argv[1], 0, 0);
    }
    printf("Delay is %d milliseconds\n", delay);
    delay *= 1000;

    dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    XevieQueryVersion(dpy, &major, &minor);
    printf("major = %d, minor = %d\n", major, minor);
    if(XevieStart(dpy))
        printf("XevieStart(dpy) finished \n");
    else
    {
        printf("XevieStart(dpy) failed, only one client is allowed to do event interception\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    XevieSelectInput(dpy, KeyPressMask | KeyReleaseMask |
                     ButtonPressMask | ButtonReleaseMask | PointerMotionMask);

    while(1)
    {
        XNextEvent(dpy, &event);
        xcme = (XClientMessageEvent *)&event;
        /* for readOnly users, send events back to Xserver immediately */
        printf("(%4d)", count++);
        switch(event.type)
        {
        case KeyPress:
            usleep(delay);
            printf(" KeyPress\n");
            print_key_event (&event);
            break;
        case KeyRelease:
            printf(" KeyRelease\n");
            break;
        case ButtonPress:
            usleep(delay);
            printf(" ButtonPress\n");
            break;
        case ButtonRelease:
            printf(" ButtonRelease\n");
            break;
        case MotionNotify:
            printf(" MotionNotify\n");
            break;
        case ClientMessage:
            printf("ClientMessage: <%s>\n", &xcme->data.b[1]);
            break;
        default:
            printf(" unknown event %x\n", event.type);
            break;
        }
        XevieSendEvent(dpy, &event, XEVIE_UNMODIFIED);
        if(count > 10000)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    XevieEnd(dpy);
    printf("XevieEnd(dpy) finished \n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libxcb-xevie0)?

Comment: No. because it is already installed but xevie.h is not added to my system.

Comment: I have a C program which includes `#include <X11/extensions/Xevie.h>`. To compile it I need to install xevie extension for X11. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that any package provides `Xevie.h`. There is a different library called `xevie.h` which is provided by `libxcb-xevie0-dev` but that's not what you need.

However, I did find [this page](http://www.filewatcher.com/d/FreeBSD/9-stable/powerpc/libXevie-1.0.3.tbz.13702.html) which has what looks like the source packages. I tried downloading `libXevie-1.0.3.tbz` and I can confirm that it contains a file called `Xevie.h` that includes the functions from your comment. In fact, the file is so small I am reproducing the entire thing here:

```
/************************************************************

Copyright (c) 2003, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a
copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"),
to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation
the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense,
and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the
Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice (including the next
paragraph) shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the
Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.  IN NO EVENT SHALL
THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER
DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

************************************************************/

#ifndef _XEVIE_H_
#define _XEVIE_H_

#include <X11/Xfuncproto.h>

#define XEVIE_UNMODIFIED    0
#define XEVIE_MODIFIED   1

#ifndef _XEVIE_SERVER_

_XFUNCPROTOBEGIN

Bool XevieQueryVersion(
    Display*            /* dpy */,
    int*            /* major_version */,
    int*            /* minor_version */
);

extern Status XevieStart(
    Display*            /* dpy */
);

Status XevieEnd(
    Display*            /* dpy */
);

Status XevieSendEvent(
    Display*                    /* dpy */,
    XEvent*         /* event */,
    int             /* data type */
);

Status XevieSelectInput(
    Display*                    /* dpy */,
    long
);


_XFUNCPROTOEND

#endif /* _XEVIE_SERVER_ */

#endif /* _XEVIE_H_ */
```

---

When looking for a specific file, you can search for it at http://packages.ubuntu.com or use `apt-file`:

```
$ apt-file search xevie.h
libxcb-xevie0-dev: /usr/include/xcb/xevie.h
```

As you can see, using `apt-file search filename` returns the package (if any) that provides the file. If `apt-file` is not installed, you will need to install it and generate its package list before running it:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
```

Comment: thanks. But it includes xcb xevie.h, while I'm looking for Xevie.h extension for X11. For example [this function](http://manned.org/XevieSelectInput/f51b98ac) does not exist in xcb xevie.h.

Comment: I think the package name is libXevie-devel and is not located in repository. But I don't know where I can download it.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus found it! See updated answer.

Comment: The problem is not just the header file. There may be .lib files and other files needed to compile the program I added in my question.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus did you download the .zip? It also contains `libXevie.la`, `libXevie.a` and `libXevie.so.1`. It is almost certainly exactly what you're after.

Comment: I downloaded ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/powerpc/packages-9-stable/All/libXevie-1.0.3.tbz Is there a standard installation procedure. For exmpple I know  I should move Xevie.h to /usr/include/X11/extensions but for other files I'm not sure!

Comment: @MinimusHeximus no idea. I suggest you post a new question about that since this one was only asking where you can find the files.

Comment: `libXevie.a, libXevie.so` are incompatible for Ubuntu. I think I need a source code to recompile them.

Answer (score 1):

[Xevie support was removed from Xorg in X11R7.5 in 2009](http://wiki.x.org/wiki/Releases/7.5/) since [it had been broken for a while and no one needed it or was interested in fixing it](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/commit/?id=f4036f6ace5f770f0fe6a6e3dc3749051a81325a).   Even if you find the library and header files to build clients, they'll fail to work with any recent Xorg server.